# Not MD5 - What Chaacters are these ? MySQL

Tags: mysql

please check the below images... i have download a script from internet. and when i am registering in forunt end. it is saving login and passwords in some format (not md5)

actually the 1st and 3rd password is different.. but it looks like same.. i am confused.. please have a look on image below.

**login and passwords in db**

```
test       test
vishnu     vishnu
test2      test1

1)  i.stack.imgur.com/Oo4mK.png
2)  i.stack.imgur.com/8w4E4.png
```

**SCRIPT I USED** : http://sourceforge.net/projects/oes/

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Comment: Inspect the 'script' you downloaded to see in what format they are saved. Alternatively, go search for the documentation of said script.

Comment: We'd have to see the script. Presumably, it encodes or hashes the password in some way.

Comment: Basically impossible to say without seeing the password hashing code. That is not any "standard" hashing, by appearance.

Comment: What's the problem you are attempting to solve?

Comment: @samurai8, david, michael, wesley, --  i have updated the question with the link to my script... :( i am really confused! :(

Comment: Looks like they're using this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_encode By the way, after looking at this package I recommend only using it as a toy, there are several security vulnerabilities I found right off the bat, plus it's been abandoned. The code is **bad**, don't use it to learn.

Comment: "i have download a script from internet" okay...

Comment: Side note: the only good thing about this project is that they used NetBeans to program this.. but the code is full off bad stuff like SQL injections (they think htmlspecialchars will help..), bad password encryption  (Like David Schwartz said), very easy Cross side scripting..., misuse of GLOBAL array..  to much trust in the $_SESSION array..  and i've only readed (140 lines off code) index.php.. so you may want to reconsider if you want to use this project on a production server..

Comment: @RaymondNijland what is  production server ? between thanks for the review...

Comment: in big lines thats an server what is live and viewable from the internet..

Comment: @RaymondNijland i didn't find any other open souce script :( even nulled :( so decided to use this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses MySQL's [ENCODE and DECODE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_encode) functions with a salt of `oespass`. This is, by the way, very bad.

Comment: thanks! :) is it possible to make it to normal.. :( i mean to MD5 format or to normal text!

Comment: you should not use MD5 or MD5 with salt.. MD5 is designed to be an very fast hash algorithm, this his is weakness because it can easy be brute forced with Cuda/OpenCL on GPU's..  And plaintext is REALLY an no go.. you should read about bcrypt function within PHP, that algortithm is designed to be slow even on GPU's